# BJQS multiple instances of slider when resizing window

Tags: javascript, jquery, window-resize, bjqs

I want to resize bjqs slider when the window resizes..

this is what i've got so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(window).resize(function(){
        $('.pagebg').bjqs({
            height      : 347,
            width       : $(window).width(),
            showcontrols : false,
            showmarkers : false,
         });
     });
});
</script>
```

I've tried to resize it using $(window).resize, but there are multiple instances running

does anyone know how I can resize it and keep only 1 instance running?

Comment: AHH!  Sorry I confused 2 questions!

Answer (score 0):

Without  using window resize event you can define you slider with a `width` option of 100% like:

```
$(function () {
    $('#dialog').bjqs({
        'showmarkers': false,
            'responsive': true,
            'width': '100 %',
            'automatic': true
    });
});
```

So it will be automatically responsive without handle its resize.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/MADrg/

Comment: Do you know how to preserve the aspect ratio of the image?